# How can I integrate Squarespace with Amazon Web Services (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, squarespace

I would like to build a site that has similar functionality to [crew.co](https://crew.co/). I want to use Squarespace for the frontend and Amazon Web Services for the backend (specifically DynamoDB and Lambda). Is it feasible to integrate the two? If yes, is it recommended?

Comment: Please do more research and be more specific. Do you want to access AWS from a server or from a browser? If from a server where is it going to be hosted? If from a browser, how are you going to authenticate your users.

Comment: Also please describe what functionality do you want to implement specifically.